# Value of object property not changed as expected

Tags: javascript, object, linked-list

I just wanted to know why in my code I have changed cr = 6 in a method,  but when printing the original obj cr value, it is not changed to 6, but remains its original value. Why? If instead I use cr.next = 6, then the value gets changed in the original `obj`. I expect `obj.next = 6`. The output generated is:

```
{
  val: 1,
  next: {
    val: 2,
    next: {
      val: 3,
      next: null
    }
  }
}
```

I expected the output to be like this:

```
{
  val: 1, 
  next: 6
}
```

```js
let obj = {
  val: 1,
  next: {
    val: 2,
    next: {
      val: 3,
      next: null
    }
  }
}

cr = obj.next;
cr = 6;
console.log(obj)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first part,

```js
cr = obj.next;
```

Means "The value of the identifier (the word `cr`) is the value at the location of memory that the object `obj.next` is"

```js
cr = 6;
```

Means "Completely disregard any previous value of `cr`; the value of the identifier `cr` is now the integer literal `6`"

---

JavaScript, unlike C/C++ (with pointers, or pass-by-reference vs pass-by-value), does not have a way to change the value of an object with a single identifier (variable name). It can change what the value of the variable is, but not the object it was previously pointing to.

Answer (score 1):

```js
let obj = {
  val: 1,
  next: {
    val: 2,
    next: {
      val: 3,
      next: null
    }
  }
}

cr = obj.next;
cr = 6;

console.log(obj)
console.log("...........................")
obj.next = 6
console.log(obj)
console.log("...........................")
console.log(cr)

cr = obj.next;
cr = 6;
```

When you do `cr = obj.next`, it makes a new variable and assigns the obj.next value to cr. After that, you assign 6 to cr so it overwrites the current value of cr and there will be only 6.

If you want an answer like `{val: 1, next: 6}`, you should write `obj.next = 6`
so you get your desire output.

I hope it helps you "keep coding".